# Ignore vEthernet adapter and use primary Ethernet instead

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a 2016 Server, that has Hyper-V installed but not being used.  This is a production server used 24/7.

The server is showing a vEthernet adapter and an Ethernet adapter.  It appears that the server is using the vEthernet adapter and not the Ethernet adapter for normal use.  Most of the connection items for the Ethernet adapter are unchecked.  They are checked for the vEthernet.

The server has occasional connectivity problems, and the network icon in the notification area indicates there is no internet access.  However, there is internet access.

**I would like to use the regular Ethernet adapter instead of vEthernet.  Is the correct procedure to check all the items on Ethernet that are currently checked on vEthernet.  Then, uncheck those options on vEthernet?**

I am considering removing Hyper-V from this server using Add/Remove Windows Features, but based on various warnings regarding removing Hyper-V, I am concerned it could cause side effects or stop the server from booting.

[image: Ethernet adapter]

[image: vEthernet adapter]

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to use the regular Ethernet adapter instead of vEthernet.
> Is the correct procedure to check all the items on Ethernet that are
> currently checked on vEthernet. Then, uncheck those options on
> vEthernet?

No. What you're seeing is because your management OS (the Hyper-V host) is sharing the physical network card with the virtual switch. The network protocols are disabled on the physical adapter and enabled on the virtual adapter that Hyper-V creates for the virtual switch. This is a perfectly acceptable configuration and is fairly common in smaller Hyper-V deployments.

If you don't want the management OS to share the physical network card with the virtual switch then you'll need to uncheck that option and assign the Hyper-V hosts ip addressing configuration to another physical network card in the server.

It's doubtful the network issues you're having are related to any of this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  If I understand, we can set the virtual switch to private (since we're not using hyper-v) to take the vEthernet switch out of the picture.  We can then plan to remove hyper-v.

Comment: Or you can just delete the virtual switch altogether, if it's not in use.

Comment: @Massimo My understanding was the virtual switch would reappear on reboots as long as hyper-v is installed.

Comment: @ChrisVesper No, virtual switches are always managed manually on server systems (only on Windows 10 there is a default one which can't be removed). You can safely remove them, if you are not using them. It's actually better to remove them before removing Hyper-V, otherwise sometimes they are not cleaned up correctly.